# Abstract page of babel[magyar] undefined

Tags: environments, babel, abstract

I am working on a document that uses a custom class. I want to change the class so that it would use the babel[magyar] instead of the english version.

However, when I try to do so, I get the following error message:

> E: .../Tester.tex:10 Undefined control sequence \begin{abstract}

My document uses a custom definition for the `abstract` environment, which works properly if babel is imported using:

```
\RequirePackage{babel}
```

Whenever I change this to:

```
\def\magyarOptions{defaults=safest}
\RequirePackage[magyar]{babel}
```

then compilation fails and I get the shown error message.

Can someone tell me how does this happens?

Update:
I was asked to provide a minimum working example instead of the specification, here I used the article class, and replaced newenvironment with renewenvironment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\def\magyarOptions{defaults=safest}
\RequirePackage[magyar]{babel}

\renewenvironment{abstract}{
    \checktoopen
    \tttypeout{\abstractname}
    \null\vfil
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    \begin{center}
    {\huge\textit{\abstractname} \par}
    \bigskip
    \end{center}
}

\begin{document}{}

\begin{abstract}

    The Thesis Abstract is written here (and usually kept to just this page). The page is kept centered vertically so can expand into the blank space above the title too\ldots
    %% TODO: megírni

\end{abstract}

\section{asda}

This is a test document.

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: But I have a custom document class :S I think I can post the same question with an article and "renewenvironment" is that okay?

Comment: Sorry, i get the same error message(s) when i remove the magyar. Also, they seem to be caused by  `\checktoopen` and  `\tttypeout` within the definition of abstract. Not the \begin{abstract} itself.

Comment: `\checktoopen` and `tttypeout` ... i know those commands. The custom class is based on `book`, which does not define an abstract environment. Hence, the class file defines it itself.

Comment: Why use `\RequirePackage` instead of `\usepackage`? The former is meant only for package writers.

Comment: @marczellm Used in the class file, but not the document the users sees. Probably copy-pasting frenzy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to ask template question by using the *ask a question* button, where you can be sure that someone familiar with the templates handles your question.

The language definition file for hungarian does not define a hungarian string for `abstract`. You gotta define one yourself.

```
\def\magyarOptions{defaults=safest}
\documentclass[magyar]{MastersDoctoralThesis}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\providecaptionname{magyar}{\abstractname}{abstractname magyar}
\renewenvironment{abstract}{
    \checktoopen
    \tttypeout{\abstractname}
    \null\vfil
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    \begin{center}
        {\huge\textit{\abstractname} \par}
        \bigskip
    \end{center}
}{\cleardoublepage}

\begin{document}{}

\begin{abstract}

    The Thesis Abstract is written here (and usually kept to just this page). The page is kept centered vertically so can expand into the blank space above the title too\ldots
                            %% TODO: megírni

\end{abstract}

\section{asda}

This is a test document.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, actually it does, but fails in this context because the template is stupid.

Comment: A template cannot be stupid, but rather badly designed. It seems that one of the authors is guilty for that silly little bug. That happens when no real testing is done and not enough coffee is consumed.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the issue has nothing to do with `magyar`.

- Neither `\checktoopen` nor `\tttypeout{}` seem to be defined in any of the packages included or in the `article` class.
- Environment (re)definitions take the form `\renewenvironment{name}{before}{after}`, where the `after` part specifies the code to be included whenever `\end{name}` is called. Your definition is missing that part.

I commented out those two commands and added a pair of empty braces at the end of the definition and it worked fine:

```
\renewenvironment{abstract}{
  %\checktoopen
  %\tttypeout{\abstractname}
  \null\vfil
  \thispagestyle{plain}
  \begin{center}
  {\huge\textit{\abstractname} \par}
  \bigskip
\end{center}
}{}
```

If you are basing your class definition in some other class out there, maybe you are missing some part of the code or a `\RequirePackage{}` command.

I hope it helps.