# How does MastersDoctoralThesis template know the language setting?

Tags: babel, document-classes

We're trying to change the [MastersDoctoralThesis](https://icecube.wisc.edu/~kjero/Thesis/Old/MastersDoctoralThesis.cls) template to use Hungarian, which is `magyar` in babel.

When running the mwe:

```
\documentclass[magyar]{MastersDoctoralThesis}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

We get weird errors e.g. `Illegal parameter number in definition of \@@magyar@now@marks.`, but pressing enough enters during compilation will get you through and the generated document has a Hungarian toc. When trying to get to the root of the problem I tried checking how the language parameter is passed to `babel`, but I don't see it anywhere. How does this `cls` know that I'm passing a language?

Bonus question would be, how to find what is giving the error, other than removing each package one-by-one. Using the base class book and babel works just fine:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

Comment: 1) Don't use `MastersDoctoralThesis` unless you have to (just look around to see how many problems it causes and how hard it can be to customise). 2) The linked version is considerably older than the one from https://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis 3) Options passed to the class are global options and available to all packages. `babel` can use the options directly without further ado.

Comment: it would probably be a good idea to report problems/bugs where they are supposed to by clucking the *askquestion* button. But I agree with moewe, don't use the template.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/307046/abstract-page-of-babelmagyar-undefined

Comment: So the answer in short is that _any_ option I give to `\documentclass` is passed on to _all_ the packages loaded with `RequirePackage`?

Comment: @Johannes_B The question was mainly about passing the options, I'd just thought I'd give context. Sorry for highjacking the question (although I did get the extra impression that this class is not very good, so that's a plus for me).